# Styling box with button click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know the best possible way to style a width of a box with button click. I want to create a code where every time i click a button, the width of the box (in this case) increases.

```
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var box = document.getElementById('bebo');

var range = ['100px','200px','300px','400px','500px','600px'];
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box.style.width = range[0],
    box.style.width = range[1],
    box.style.width = range[2],
    box.style.width = range[3],
    box.style.width = range[4],
    box.style.width = range[5];


});
```

This is what i tried but it doesn't work. I've also tried this:

```
var range = ['100px','200px','300px','400px','500px','600px'];
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box.style.width = range.shift();
});
```

The range.shift() option did work for me but i don't feel like that's the efficient way to code for what i want.

I would really like some advice.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please refer the [ask] link for more details.

Comment: the code with the range[0] to [5] doesn't style the width of the box .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually works fine, but since it mutates the array, you cannot reuse it. In addition, when the array is empty, more clicks would cause the width to be `undefined`.

I would use a counter. You can increment the counter, and when you reach the end of the array, you can go back to the start (like in this example).

**Example:**

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var box = document.getElementById('bebo');

var range = ['100px', '200px', '300px', '400px', '500px', '600px'];
var counter = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.style.width = range[counter];
  
  counter = (counter + 1) % range.length;
});
```

```css
#bebo {
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Btn</button>

<div id="bebo"></div>
```

Comment: So what does `% range.length` exactly do in this case? @OriDrori

Comment: The % operator gives you the remainder of dividing one number with another. In this case it will the counter to be within 0 `array.length - 1`.